# Search for similar words using an index

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, fuzzy-search

I need to search over a DB table using some kind of fuzzy search like the one from oracle and using indexes since I do not want a table scan(there is a lot of data).

I want to ignore case, language special stuff(ñ, ß, ...) and special characters like _, (), -, etc...

Search for "maria (cool)" should get "maria- COOL" and "María_Cool" as matches.

Is that possible in Oracle in some way?

About the case, I think it can be solved created the index directly in lower case and searching always lower-cased. But I do not know how to solve the special chars stuff.
I thought about storing the data without special chars in a separated column and searching on that returning the real one, but I am not 100% sure where that is the perfect solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [UTL_MATCH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_match.htm) can help.

But you can also create a function based index on, lets say, something like this:

```
regexp_replace(your_column, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ')
```

And try to match like this:

```
...
WHERE regexp_replace(your_column, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ') = 
      regexp_replace('maria (cool)' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ')
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ac2c/3) It's not complete, but can be a start

Comment: looks nice, but what about language specific stuff like accents or ñ? :S. Thanks!

Comment: See my sqlfiddle demo, it contains some examples for special chars - I used the `translate function`

Comment: Nice, though I will have to specify all characters there. Just the last question! :P Would that be still better(more efficient) than duplicating the column with the "degraded" data? Thx!

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez, I don't know if a function based index on a column is faster or slower then a regular one, but it will keep the integrity of your data. When you add a calculated column you need to maintain it (think what happens if you update the column and forget to update the indexed one...)

Comment: I ended up using convert('María','US7ASCII') in convination with replace! thx :)

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez, Nice! but aren't you afraid of getting `?` for some characters ?

Comment: exactly. The whole thing is: I need to scape special characters like ?, _, (, etcc so no problem. Solution: Replace special chars(?,_, etc), convert and replace ? by _ (so it match any char). It will do that niño match niBo. But it is is more than acceptable for a fuzzy search:)