# Oracle regular expression with different searching parameters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like

I've sample data of plate numbers of different countries of `varchar2` datatype, no restrictions at all:

```
plate_number
-------
KL AB 1234
DB-2034
kl_c_3341
12/34
other123
```

I need to get all the above results in a select query, for the input: (sample syntax)

```
WHERE plate_number in('kl-ab-1234', 'db 2034', 'klC3341', 'oTher 123', '1234');
```

The searching inputs may be separated with or without spaces, slashes, hyphens, uppercase, or lowercase.

I've tried using LIKE, substr, regexp_substr and regexp_replace too, but I'm not getting the desired output.

The above may be *easy* or *not logical*, this is only for my practice for an upcoming use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336295/search-for-similar-words-using-an-index

Comment: yeah really!!. Let me try with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may employ a regex enumerating all possible input patterns as alternatives. remember to include start/end anchors to maximize pattern specifity and avoid partial matches. the following template takes on your sample set:

```
WHERE REGEXP_INSTR (
          REGEXP_REPLACE(plate_number, '[ -/]', '')
        ,             '^('
                   || '[[:alpha:]]{1,3}[[:alpha:]]{1,2}[[:digit:]]{2,4}'
            || '|' || '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}'
            || '|' || '[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]{3}'
            || '|' || '[[:digit:]]{4}'
                   || ')$'
        , 1, 1, 0
        , 'i'
      ) > 0
```

the first pattern is based on first-hand knowledge of the structure of german number plate texts, you'd add additional patterns as needed. as the separators are optional anyway and as they are outside the character/number range they can be elided prior to the actual matching. expect patterns with overlapping match sets, keeping them separate adds vastly to maintainability and does no harm since you don't need to classify.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @A.B.Cade, and this is what I got from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336295/search-for-similar-words-using-an-index)

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table3
WHERE lower(regexp_replace(word, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')) IN(
lower(regexp_replace('kl-ab-1234' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')),
lower(regexp_replace('db 2034' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')),
lower(regexp_replace('klC3341' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')),
lower(regexp_replace('oTher 123' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')),
lower(regexp_replace('1234 ' , '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')));
```

any other good solution are welcome.